# How to sum 100 to all pixel values of an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to sum 100 (delimiting the 255 limit) to all pixel values of an image, how can I do it? The examples I found in internet are like this:

```
gray_2[np.where(gray == 0)] = 255
```

but in my case I want to manipulate all of them.. how it can be done?

I want to get all the image pixel values and sum 100 to that value.

Comment: I do not understand what you want. Do you want the sum of all pixels whose gray level value is 0? Where does 100 come in?  How do you want to manipulate the pixels?

Comment: Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I want to get all the image pixel values and sum 100 to that value.

Comment: Still do not understand what "sum 100" means. Do you want to add 100 to each value in gray?  `gray = cv2.add(gray, 100)` OpenCV add will clip uint8 values between 0 and 255 automatically. Or you can  do `(gray + 100).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a datatype that will not overflow if you add 100 to it (i.e. uint16) then you can do simply use numpy.add() to do it:

```
gray_2 = np.add(gray, 100)
```

Most images are of type uint8 though so you'd want to clamp the output to a range of 0 to 255.  But when you do the add, you'd want to use a datatype that didn't overflow.  So there is some casting (astype()) needed:

```
gray_2 = np.add(gray.astype(np.uint16), 100).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: Basically, you cast the matrix to uint16 so you can add 100 without overflowing, add, clamp the output from 0-255, then convert it back to uint8 so that your other functions still use it as a normal matrix.

Comment: And if I have a RGB image?

Comment: If you want to add 100 to every component (BGR) you can do use the same code, just pass in the color image instead of the gray image

Comment: if you want to add a "color" (basically, an array of values, or only add to the red value, for example) it is a little harder but you can use "broadcasting".  So if you have a color c, you can pass c[None, None, :] instead of 100 to the add function.  I'm pretty sure that will work

Answer (score 0):

simply add 100 to all pixels?

```py
yourimage += 100
```

adds 100 to every channel of every pixel. that is the simplest way to express this. it is functionally equivalent to `np.add`.

note that this can **overflow**. if you want to prevent that, there are two options.

option 1: `cv2.add`. this OpenCV function uses *saturation arithmetic*.

```py
yourimage = cv2.add(yourimage, 100)
```

option 2: `np.clip` and some type conversions. assuming your source image is of type `np.uint8`:

```py
yourimage = (yourimage.astype(np.uint16) + 100).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

converts to uint16, which can hold those values without wrapping, then clips to the range 0..255, then converts back to uint8.